# why does pointer to array fails to return as **

Tags: c++

I don't understand why the following fails:

```
#include<string>
class  Foo
{
  public:
     std::string** GetStr(){return str;}    

 private:
   std::string * str[10];
};
```

Thanks

Comment: What does it fail to do? It compiles for me.

Comment: yes... it does for me too, i had a different data type

Comment: then if it still doesn't work update your question to include your exact code with your types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you tag this as C++ and C. Which is it? C does not have a string class. If it is C++, please remove the C tag, it is misleading (they are not the same language!).

Edit: I misunderstood what you are trying to do. Your method should compile. You just have to remember to dereference the returned str to get the string.

I rarely deal with double indirection, but you have to do something like this to set the string:

```
*(*str) = "STR"; //or
*(str[i]) = "STR";
```

I don't know how you would use the address operator here, because it returns a reference and not a pointer.

to set the string in the str array. Your method is really weird. The problem is that the compiler doesn't know that you want to dereference a string, so it tries to dereference a char*.

I do not understand why you want to do it this way, though. It would be better to do this:

```
std::string str[10];
std::string* GetStr() { return str; }
```

Comment: removed the "C" tag. You can do that w/ rep >= 500.

Comment: I put  string* str[] for example purposes,  I use different classes in my case

Comment: yes... good point, it is C++ question given string classes... though the rule I ma interested is in both languages..

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what you are trying to do. Let me edit my post.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem with the C tag is - even if the sample code uses C++ classes, the issue about the relationship of an array of pointers and pointer-to-pointers (which is what the question seems to be about) is the same in C and C++.

Comment: Yes, but he is programming in C++. He uses std::string, which is not in C, so I don't think a C tag is honest.